# Why Rails create my text_fields with the same "name" value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, gsub

I have the next code:

```
text.gsub(/%{(\w*)}/, text_field_tag(/(?<=%{)[^%]*(?=})/.match(text), nil)).html_safe
```

So if I have the next text input: `%{abc}`, it will replace by `%{abc}` with text_field and will call its `name` as `abc`. But if I have `%{abc} -- %{cba}` it will add 2 text_fields but with the same `name` values, `abc` and `abc`. But I need to make it as `abc` and for the second text_field `cba`.

What's wrong and how can I improve my code?

Comment: Try `scan` since `match` only searches for 1 match: `text.scan(/(?<=%{)[^%]*(?=})/)`. Maybe you need to adjust the code a bit more to account for multiple extracted values.

Comment: When I replaced `match` with `scan`, it gave me an error: `undefined method `scan' for /(?<=%{)[^%]*(?=})/:Regexp` @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You cannot just replace `match` with `scan` in your code. It must be `string.scan(/regex/)`. See my first comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it works, but it added to the name value of both my textfields `abc cba`. But I need `text_field_1(abc), text_field_2(cba)`. Can you help me with it please?